# How to skip a state on transitioning "back" to a state in angular 1.5 and ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following states:

`product -> payment -> receipt`

I want to prevent users from going back from `receipt` state to `payment` state and go to the `product` state instead.

Ideally when transitioning from `payment` to `receipt` I want to "pop" the last state so that hitting back from the `receipt` state the browser will go back to the `product` state (e.g skip the `payment` state).

**What is the best way to do this?**

I'm using angular 1.5 and ui-router.

Comment: I dont want to disable back, I want to skip a state.

Comment: Oh yea sorry, I provided an answer. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$stateChangeStart` and forward the user.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router"]);
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(
      event, 
      next, 
      toParams, 
      fromState, 
      fromParams, 
      options
  ) {
    //prevent back from receipt to payment and forward to product view
    if (next.name === 'payment' 
        && fromState.name === 'receipt'
        && toParams.preventBack === "true" //additional software switch
    ) {
        $state.go('product');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey lin, this is very ad-hoc. I'm looking for a more robust solution - for example being able to set "preventBack" on the state.data and handle the "pop" in the $stateChangeStart. In ionic i'm doing this `this.$ionicHistory.currentView(this.$ionicHistory.backView());` - this pops the last state from the stack and when i hit back on the next state i'll go back to the previous one.

Comment: @haki Why is this unstable? You can still have a software switch inside `$stateChangeStart` by using state params e.g.. In that way you are still be able to "preventBack" and handle the "pop". It should be fine.

Comment: If you kick a state from the history, the user is unable to use forward in the correct way. In that way the user would go like `product -> payment -> receipt` back `receipt -> product ` forward `product  -> receipt ` instead of `product -> payment -> receipt` back `receipt -> product ` forward `product  -> payment`. But well, this is on you. I just give you one solution to your problem. Cheers m8